# How to convert SQL query to Linq in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

How can I convert this SQL query to a linq expression?

```
Select distinct Clients.Id 
From Clients
Join Orders On Clients.Id = Orders.ClientsId and Orders.Date < DATEADD(DD, -Clients.Term, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Yes, I know about the `Database.SqlQuery<>()` function. Probably it's the best solution in terms of performance. But code uniformity is preferred, so I need to use linq.

Here is my solution:

```
var outdatedClients = context.Clients.GroupJoin(context.Orders,
client => client.Id,
order => order.ClientId,
(client, order) => new 
{
    Id = client.Id,
    Term = client.Term,
    Orders = order.Any(order => DbFunctions.DiffDays(order.Date, _datenow) > client.Term)
})
.ToList()
.Where(client => client.Orders == true);
```

But maybe it`s possible to do it more elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is all freehand so I apologize if there are some syntax issues...**

Assuming you are using EF/EFCore and your classes are structured similar to the following:

```
public class Client
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Term { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date {get; set; }
}
```

Then something like the following should match your SQL query?:

```
var clients = await context.Clients.Include(c => C.Orders)
.Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.Date < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-c.Term)))
.ToArrayAsync();
```

You could also distinct the result, but assuming that 'Id' is your primary key for `Client` then it shouldn't be necessary as they will be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Considering of the size of db your query takes much more time but seems to be quite clear for maintain the code in the future.

Comment: Include is not needed in this query.